# Why distinct produces syntax error when mixed with other none distinct rows?

Tags: sql, mysql

All these attempts fail:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(row1,row2), * FROM foo

SELECT *, DISTINCT (row1,row2) FROM foo

SELECT *, DISTINCT row1,row2 FROM foo
```

I want to fetch all rows but not duplicate rows on `row1` & `row2`

PS. I don't want to use GROUP By.

Thanks!

Comment: When you write row1, row2, do you actually mean col1, col2? If not, can you explain what you mean by row?

Comment: Can you also explain why you don't want to do this using GROUP BY?

Comment: It may be a good idea to provide some example data and an example output as it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use DISTINCT on the entire row, not part of it.

> PS. I don't want to use GROUP By.

That's a shame, because GROUP BY would have been the correct way to do this.